# Using =GetPivotData in GoogleSheet to get specific Grand Total

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use =GetPivotData formula to dynamically pull specific sum totals (40% & 80% Sell-Out Probability in my example) into a table. I may not fully understand how to use the formula, but everything I've tried has returned an error.

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oa_qRXEaYOfMkGg5Og5YKEHDErztXMiJDZVFZRuPvB0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to see what to include to give us so that we have the information we need to help.

Answer (score 2):

This formula seems to pull the answer you want, if I understand your question.

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("SUM of Sales",H2,"Sell-Out Probability","40%")
```

This would go in N8 of your sample sheet.
N9 would have the same formula, but with "80%" as the last value.

Let me know if this helps.